# Nothings happens to the new element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code, which highlights (fadein/out) the replied comment (its a div element).

I show only 10 last comments on the page
If the comment is found, then I highlight it (working fine), otherwise I load all comments and then try to highlight necessary one. But after loadAllComments function in the else clause the hide() method is not working - I wonder why.

```
function showReply(reply){
var p = getElement(reply);

if (p) {
    $("#" + reply).animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 200, function () {
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + reply).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 200, function () {
        });
    }, 1000);

}
else{
    loadAllComments(); //load all elements. working fine
    $("#"+reply).hide(); //nothing happens. :-(
}

function loadAllComments() {
    deleteComments();
    $('.show-more-button').hide();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', api_url + 'video_comments/?video=' + video_id, true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                var comments = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                for (var i = comments.results.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
                    $('.comment-content-box').append(showComment(comments.results[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
function deleteComments(){
    var comments_count = $('.comment-content-box').children('div').length;
    for (var i=0; i < comments_count; i++){
        $('.comment-render-box').remove();
    }
}
function showComment(comment) {
    return "<div>" // example, there is plenty of code, but it's just a return function
}
```

Comment: please add `html` code too then only we will able to do something

Comment: Does `getElement(reply)` return the dom element for reply? If so, you don't need to do `$('#'+reply)`, you can simply do `$(p)`, which may fix the selector problem occurring in the loadAllComments function.

Comment: It depends on what `reply` is since you're using that to query the DOM. If the query returns nothing (which is likely the case here) then calling `.hide()` will have no effect. It's also possible you have a race-condition between calling `loadAllComments()` and `$("#"+reply).hide();`.

Comment: Is this code in a document ready function?

Comment: After `loadAllComments()`, put a `console.log("#"+reply);` and make sure you're getting what you expect.  If that is valid, use your browser's inspector to see what is happening to the DOM during `loadAllComments()`. Maybe the reply is getting stomped on?

Comment: @AndréDion reply is a string - its and ID of html element. I added console.log and see the id of the element, which I expect to see.

Comment: guys, I forgot to mention: loadAllComments() deletes all divs with comments and then appends them again. So I checked the count of divs after this function - its 0. It seems that they haven't appeared yet on the page at the time of the alert, but appear some time later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing an XHR which is asynchronous. Supply a callback function to `loadAllComments` to be executed after your XHR completes:

```
function loadAllComments(callback) {
    deleteComments();
    $('.show-more-button').hide();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', api_url + 'video_comments/?video=' + video_id, true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                var comments = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                for (var i = comments.results.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
                    $('.comment-content-box').append(showComment(comments.results[i]));
                }

                // xhr is complete and comments are now in DOM
                callback();
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

...

// usage
loadAllComments(function() {
    $('#' + reply).hide();
});
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. In my  case (i dont know why) it works only with timeout >=1000

Comment: Are you loading data over HTTP? If so, you need to call `hide` from its response callback. You should really add your `loadAllComments` code in your question.

Comment: Your issue was you were running asynchronous code synchronously. Answer updated.

Comment: wow, magic! Thank you very much. As soon as I earn my reputation you'll get +1 :-)